# Why is mix-blend-mode lighten not working in Next.js 13 but working in React with exactly the same code?

Tags: next.js13

I'm working on a project where I'm converting React code to Next.js 13. I've got a div with backgorund Image and linear gradient. `mix-blend-mode: lighten;` is working as expected in the React code but making the entire div disappear in Next.js 13. Below is the css:

```
.newsletter_right {
  width: 65%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 55, 0.681), rgba(0, 71, 38, 0.582)),
    url("../../../public/assets/newsletter.png");
  /* mix-blend-mode: lighten; */ /*This doesn't work with Next.js 13. It gave me a nightmare to fix*/
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
}
```

setting mix-blend-mode to normal or others worked but not lighten. What could cause this?